# In APIFlask, can auth be used to protect the Swagger endpoints?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, apiflask

I have an APIFlask app that servers Swagger UI and OpenAPI spec endpoints.  (`/docs` and `/openapi.json`, respectively.)

I have successfully implementer JWT-based Bearer auth to protect my own endpoints, but I don't see any obvious way to protect the auto-generated Swagger UI and OpenAPI spec endpoints.

Suggestions?

Comment: This function is not implemented yet, i'm going to support this feature in this [PR](https://github.com/apiflask/apiflask/pull/508). have any ideas or suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [version 2.1.0](https://github.com/apiflask/apiflask/releases/tag/2.1.0), we can add the auth decorators with the `SPEC_DECORATORS` or `DOCS_DECORATORS`  configuration.

See more with: https://apiflask.com/openapi/#protect-openapi-endpoints